# segment merge in solr not happening

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I find the Lucene segments in the backend is not merging and the segment count increases to a lot. I changed the merge policy from `LogByteSizeMergePolicy` to `TieredMergePolicy`

I tried altering properties according to the `solr` documentation, but still, my segments are high.

I am using solr 6.1.X. **The index data is stored in  HDFS.**

**My index config of solrconfig.xml:**

```
<indexConfig>
    <writeLockTimeout>1000</writeLockTimeout>
    <commitLockTimeout>10000</commitLockTimeout>
    <maxIndexingThreads>15</maxIndexingThreads>
    <useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
    <ramBufferSizeMB>1024</ramBufferSizeMB>
    <mergePolicy class="org.apache.lucene.index.TieredMergePolicy">
          <int name="maxMergeAtOnce">10</int>
          <int name="segmentsPerTier">1</int>
    </mergePolicy>
    <mergePolicyFactory class="org.apache.solr.index.TieredMergePolicyFactory">
          <int name="maxMergeAtOnce">10</int>
          <int name="segmentsPerTier">10</int>
    </mergePolicyFactory>
    <lockType>hdfs</lockType>
    <deletionPolicy class="solr.SolrDeletionPolicy">
        <str name="maxCommitsToKeep">1</str>
        <str name="maxOptimizedCommitsToKeep">0</str>
    </deletionPolicy>
</indexConfig>

The only way we optimize is by force merging which is IO costly and also takes hours to complete.
```

I have a cluster of three shards and replication factor as 2.

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong

Comment: In order to get more detailed answer please provide info stream output into your question

Answer (score 0):

## Theory

In order to understand how merge policy works under the hood you can read the [following post](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/02/visualizing-lucenes-segment-merges.html)

In few words merge policy does not affect segments count it just decides which segments to merge. So the main question is: How many segments do you have? What is the problem?

Another important factor is number of indexing threads - each thread creates it's own thread local segment. In other words 15 threads create 15 segments on disk.

Please, be aware by using force merge API - this call is not IO throttled at all. So it can consume all of the I/O on your nodes, leaving nothing for search and potentially making your system unresponsive.

## Practice

You can enable `<infoStream>true</infoStream>` in your `solrconfig.xml` which will produce something like this into Solr log:

```
   IW: commit: done writing segments file "segments_2"
   IFD: now checkpoint "_cx(6.6.1):c721" [1 segments ; isCommit = true]
   IFD: deleteCommits: now decRef commit "segments_1"
   IFD: delete StoreDirectory.deleteFile: delete file segments_1 
   TMP: findMerges: 1 segments 
   TMP: seg=_cx(6.6.1):c721 size=0.054 MB [floored]
   TMP: allowedSegmentCount=1 vs count=1 (eligible count=1) tooBigCount=0
   MS: now merge
   MS: no more merges pending; now return
```

Where all decisions are logged with informative description for each component:

- IW - index writer
- IFD - deletion policy
- TMP - tiered merge policy
- MS - merge scheduler